# I want toarray in JavaScript? Where is it my fault?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add This code to my page and I want to complete city when user tap a zipcode 
and my alert dosen't show

```js
var obj = {
  "01400": "ABERGEMENT-CLÉMENCIAT",
  "01640": "ABERGEMENT-DE-VAREY",
  "01500": "AMBÉRIEU-EN-BUGEY",
  "01330": "AMBÉRIEUX-EN-DOMBES",
  "01300": "AMBLÉON",
  "01500": "AMBRONAY",
  "01500": "AMBUTRIX",
  "01300": "ANDERT-ET-CONDON",
  "01350": "ANGLEFORT",
  "01100": "APREMONT",
  "01110": "ARANC",
  "01230": "ARANDAS",
  "01100": "ARBENT",
  "01300": "ARBIGNIEU",
  "01190": "ARBIGNY"
};
var myVariable = obj .01400;
alert(myVariable);
```

Comment: What is `97433` ?

Comment: The `object.property` syntax only works when the property name is a valid identifier. You can however use `obj[97433]`.

Comment: this A keybord fault , I fix it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, there is no key named `97433` in your object

Secondly, even if there was you cannot use property accesors with object keys which begin with a number. You need to use bracket notation.

Lastly, use `console.log()` for debugging as `alert()` coerces types and blocks the UI logic.

```
var myVariable = obj['97433'];
console.log(myVariable);
```

Comment: yes thank's a lot , I already fix It